# osCommerce Authorize.net confirm payment time out

Tags: oscommerce, authorize.net, payment-processing

i am using oscommerce for my client.

i have integrate authorize.net payment module for payment using credit card.

when i am checkout and confirm payment after enter credit card detail..

page is time out and give the following error.

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

      This transaction has been approved.

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

any one know why this problem occure..

If any help it would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This means the relay response used by OSCommerce is not returning a successful response to Authorize.Net in time (5 seconds). As a result Authorize.Net is assuming the page is not functioning and displaying that message. I'm not familiar with OSCommerce to know how to fix it but hopefully this points you in the right direction.